# JavaScript enabling on browser when a button is clicked (not automatically)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a lot of JavaScript on my site (currently under construction). My worry is if some of the client side's system has JavaScript disabled then my site will "miserably fail".

I know that we cannot programatically override to enable JavaScript as it would be a security issue. But what I want is if the client side system has JavaScript disabled then a popup should appear with a button so that when the user clicks the button automatically JS will be enabled no matter in what browser he is viewing the site.

I am asking this because I saw the same thing myself when I viewed some other site.

Comment: Please link the site that did this; I want to see for myself how they got around security restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. You can however display instructions on the page on how to enable JavaScript, but considering that people who disable JavaScript usually know what they are doing they'll know how to enable it themselves.

I'd say there are very few people who accidentally disable JavaScript, so your worries are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a popup to appear then you need to make it happen using javascript, so I guess the answer is that you can just ignore the very small percentage of people who have javascript disabled for their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Instead of showing a message through JavaScript that tells the user to enable JavaScript you do it the other way around.

By default you show a message, in a div for example, and when JavaScript is enabled you hide the div. You only use JavaScript to enhance the user experience but offer a 'reasonable' experience when the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled. Reasonable could mean in your case an empty page with some text that explains why you really need JavaScript.